# How to open Html page present in document directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am having a folder in my document directory in that folder i am having main.html page i want to open that html page in webview can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
     //First get the path of the documents directory
     NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"main.html"];

     //Load webview 
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", documentsDirectoryPath];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [webviewForHelp loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: My folder is in document directory..@Girish

Comment: please read my answer now I edited it to get the path of documents directory

Comment: I am not getting i will tell in few minutes..@ Girish

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
I used this but i am not getting...@ Girish
    NSString *fileLoc = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/main.html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLoc];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebview loadRequest:request];
    [myView addSubview:myWebview];

Comment: First line in my answer gives you the path of documents directory. If you have folder in it then pass Documents/Foldername & then pass the name of your html file. If main.html is documents directory itself, then you directly pass main.html which I mentioned it in first line. After this load the web view, I tried this code in my sample app & it works fine for me. Try again & let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Get your `DocumentDirectory` path and append your `main.html` to that path.

```
NSString *documentPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"main.html"];
```

then load it using

```
NSURL* address = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:address] ; 
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: How to get Document directory path..@arthan.v

Comment: NSString *documentPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"main.html"];
you told this line but my file is in document directory..@ arthan.v

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *basePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; I used this but i am not getting...@ Girish NSString *fileLoc = [basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/main.html"]; NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileLoc]; NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [myWebview loadRequest:request]; [myView addSubview:myWebview];
@arthan.v

Comment: surely friend, :) always @user1903049

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"html"];

 NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```